# Evaluating SVG Filter Performance (Alphamap)

Tags: svg, svg-filters

Is there a known tool to evaluate SVG Filter Performance? I am generating an alphamap using the following SVG node, but am struggling a little with the performance.

```
<feColorMatrix result="alphaOut" in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 1, 0 0 0 0 1, 0 0 0 0 1, 0 0 0 1 0" />
```

Is there a way to quantify rendering times for SVG filters? Alternativly, does anybody know a better way to extract alpha information using SVG filters?

Comment: why not use the SourceAlpha directly?

Comment: sourceAlpha is the sources alpha channel set on explicity black pixels, whereas his filter sets the sources alpha channel on white pixels. It's a white alpha Map instead of the default black alpha map...

Comment: i have added a simple filter that uses SourceAlpha to the performance test...

Comment: Sorry - I meant SourceAlpha with an invert(100%) css filter? My general experience is that color transformations (colormatrix, componenttransfer) are fast, anything with a composite/merge/blend is a little slower, and lighting effects (specular/diffuse) are deadly slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea for measuring performance taken from https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/07/How-to-measure-browser-graphics-performance

```js
function draw(x) {
  var g = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g")
  g.id = "canvas"
  canvas.parentNode.replaceChild(g, canvas)
  for (var i = 1; i < x; i++) {
    var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect")
    rect.setAttribute("width", "100")
    rect.setAttribute("height", "100")
    rect.setAttribute("filter", "url(#" + filter + ")")
    rect.setAttribute("fill", "rgba(128,128,128,0.8)")
    rect.setAttribute("x", Math.random() * 300)
    rect.setAttribute("y", Math.random() * 300)
    g.appendChild(rect)
  }

}
var filter = "f1"
var t, previousTime;
var drawLoad = 1;
var slowCount = 0;
var maxSlow = 10;
// Note, you might need to polyfill performance.now and requestAnimationFrame
t = previousTime = performance.now();
var tick = function() {
  var maximumFrameTime = 1000 / 30; // 30 FPS
  t = performance.now();
  var elapsed = t - previousTime;
  previousTime = t;
  if (elapsed < maximumFrameTime || slowCount < maxSlow) {
    if (elapsed < maximumFrameTime) {
      drawLoad += 10;
    } else {
      slowCount++;
    }
    draw(drawLoad);
    requestAnimationFrame(tick);
  } else {
    // found maximum sustainable load at 30 FPS
    document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = ("could draw " + (drawLoad) + " in " +
      maximumFrameTime + " ms");
  }

};
requestAnimationFrame(tick);
```

```css
svg {
  background: beige
}
```

```html
<button onclick="filter='f1';drawLoad=1;slowCount=0;requestAnimationFrame(tick)">test filter 1</button>
<button onclick="filter='f2';drawLoad=1;slowCount=0;requestAnimationFrame(tick)">test filter 2</button>
<div id="res"></div>

<svg width="400" height="400">
  <filter id="f1">
    <feColorMatrix result="alphaOut" in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 1
        0 0 0 0 1
        0 0 0 0 1
        0 0 0 1 0" />
  </filter>
  <filter id="f2">
    <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode dx="1" dy="1" in="SourceAlpha" />
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
  <g id="canvas">
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: That's a very nice snippet. (Interestingly filter 1 performs better for me.) Working on finding a faster version of the white alpha map using this to test the results now.

Comment: i can confirm your findings. feColorMatrix was faster for me as well. 
When using this snippet you might consider increasing the size of the canvas and the created rects. It will reduce the impact of DOM manipulation on the result...